# Non-Integer Class Labels Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn

Quick SVM question for scikit-learn. When you train an SVM, it's something like

```
from sklearn import svm
s = svm.SVC()
s.fit(training_data, labels)
```

Is there any way for `labels` to be a list of a non-numeric type? For instance, if I want to classify vectors as 'cat' or 'dog,' without having to have some kind of external lookup table that encodes 'cat' and 'dog' into 1's and 2's. When I try to just pass a list of strings, I get ...

`ValueError: invalid literal for float(): cat`

So, it doesn't look like just shoving strings in `labels` will work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The recent version of sklearn is able to use string as the labels. For example:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
y = ['dog', 'cat']
clf.fit(x,y)

yhat = clf.predict([[1,2,5]])
print yhat[0]
```

Answer (score 21):

Passing strings as classes directly is on my todo, but it is not supported in the SVMs yet.
For the moment, we have the [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder) that can do the book keeping for you.

[edit]This should work now out of the box[/edit]

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version, you can pass the strings in labels.
But in the previous version, you need to encode the labels first with LabelEncoder.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import svm
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
new_labels = le.fit_transform(["cat", "cat", "dog", "bat"])
le.inverse_transform([0, 0, 1, 2])
s = svm.SVC()
s.fit(training_data, labels)
```

To get the original labels back use

```
le.inverse_transform([0, 0, 1, 2])
```

output will be

```
["cat", "cat", "dog", "bat"]
```