# How to use labels to classify text with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have a NLP task (text clasification). I extracted some bigrams like this:

```
training_data = [[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'text')],
        [('and', 'one'), ('one', 'more')]]
```

Then i could use some vectorizer like this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher

fh = FeatureHasher(input_type='string')

X = fh.transform(((' '.join(x) for x in sample)
                  for sample in training_data))
print X.toarray()

[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

This is how svm algorithm can be used to classify:

```
from sklearn import svm
s = svm.SVC()
lables = [HAM, SPAM]    
s.fit(training_data, labels)
```

How can i use labels in the above brigam (i.e. `training_data`) in order to classify?, for example:

```
data = [[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'text'), 'SPAM'], 
[('and', 'one'), ('one', 'more'), 'HAM']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above code, assuming that we have a feature vector named `doc`, if you write:

```
result = s.predict (doc)
```

`result` should be either '0' or '1'. So the prediction result is numeric. Thus, its better to assign the labels accordingly. However, if you still want to assign a string label, then you can assume that for example label 'a' is equivalent to '1' and 'b' to '0'. I know that unlike `scikit` in `nltk` the labels are string by default, but is there any difference?

**Edit 1:** I can see from your first edit that you might have a misconception about feature vectors and  their labels. First of all, the type of label you assign doesn't affect the outcome, meaning that if you assign a class label as spam and one as non-spam the classifier doesn't automagically detect spams and non-spams; the classification depends on your feature vector and then for comparison sake a class label. So if you say, I would assume that in my code 0 represents a SPAM and 1 represents a HAM and you would label your data accordingly, it works and its enough. Second issue is that I'm not sure if you know how a bigram feature vector should look like because of the way you represented your data by writing the bellow code:

```
data = [[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'text'), 'SPAM'], 
[('and', 'one'), ('one', 'more'), 'HAM']]
```

A bigram feature vector should contain all possible features present in your data set, and then for representing each document you have to assign a 1 to all the feature present in that document and a 0 to the rest. As an example, I will rewrite your above example in the correct form:

```
Features:   'this is'  'is a'   'a text'  'and one'   'one more'     Label
doc 1:         1         1         1          0           0           SPAM (or as I explained 0)
doc 2:         0         0         0          1           1           HAM (or as I explained 1)
```

Now, we can write the feature vectors of the above documens in the following form:

```
data = [([1,1,1,0,0),(0)],[(0,0,0,1,1),(1)]]
```

Notice that the label for the first document is 0 (or SPAM) and for the second document its 1 (or HAM). I tried to make a very clear example. When using scikit you might prefer using numpy arrays instead of list. But my example is clear. Reading this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003291/n-grams-with-naive-bayes-classifier/14025991#14025991) about bigrams along with my answer might help you. Let me know if you had further questions, but try to think about the above example.

**Edit 2:**  Just in case you are wondering how to write the labels in the variable `labels` in your code: for each document (which is converted to a feature vector representation) you have to have a corresponding label. In your code array `X` contains the feature vectors, so in `labels` you have to have labels with the same position in array as `X` corresponding to each feature vector. Thus, assuming that you have 100 documents (50 SPAM or 0 and 50 HAM or 1) your labels should look like this:

```
labels = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...]
```

but this depends on how you have ordered your data. Some classifiers would take the labels like above and some would take 0s and 1s interlayed, such as:

```
labels = [0,1,0,1,0,1, ...]
```

In svm.SVC() you can use the later, however, make sure that your feature vectors are also interlayed and correspond to the right labels.

Comment: I edited the question, how about using string labels instead of numeric or boolean labels?

Comment: @ml_guy I have made a second edit about how the labels should look like. Is it solved now?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What about using string labels insted of numeric ones (e.g. 'POS', 'NEG', 'NEU'). For the specific case of svm could i use string labels?.

Comment: NO! I explained to you that you could keep a record of string tags and link them with the numeric labels in your code. This question was also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300160/non-integer-class-labels-scikit-learn